# SQL custom sort order with percentile question

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with roughly 600,000 records, that I need to do percentiles on with a customized order to the ID keys. The key isn't unique as they are labeled TMC_CODE, which details a set length of highway. For these 600,000 records I have about 36 TMCs, as I want SQL server to output the TMCs in an custom order that isn't alphabetical or numerical. The code I have thus far is:

```
WITH PERCENTILES AS (SELECT TMC_code, EPOCH, percentile_CONT(.98)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(speed as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS TTAV_P_98 FROM [dbo].[I40]

SELECT TMC_code, TTAV_P_98 FROM Percentiles
GROUP BY TMC_code, TTAV_P_98 ORDER BY *no idea what to put here*
```

The problem is the nomenclature for TMCs isn't alphabetical or numerical. An example TMC is 113+04489 or 113P04489 or 113N04489.

Comment: Please describe how they should be sorted.

Comment: Alternating between + and P TMCs of the same numerical  value. So 113+04491,113P04491, 113+04492,113P04492 and so on.

Comment: Ben, it looks like you are trying to determine at which EPOCH(s) a given TMC_code is within (or outside of) the 98% percentile travel-time.  Is that correct? If so, then your final SELECT should reflect that.  Please edit your question to explain "why" you need EPOCH included in the WITH clause. I will post an "answer" once I know this information.

Comment: For each TMC I want the 98th percentile of speed and yes, the epoch within the with statement is not needed. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: When I do a case function I still cannot get a custom order to work.